# How to get Last Row Count Value in linq

Tags: linq, entity-framework

Is it possible to get the last row count value without making query to database using linq ?

I have a scenario where I make a linq  query to find some records and count too  but when I query second time using linq then I want the count last effected rows without making query to database

Thanks

Comment: What is a "last row count value"? Is `count` a column or the record count?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific, maybe post some code/pseudo-code? You are running a query and then want to get a count of what afterwards? The number of rows that came back?

Comment: In SQL Server there is function called @@RowCount which returns the number of rows affected by the last statement. I want some similar linq statement without query to database like int count=db.tablename.count() which is same as select count(*) from tablename

Comment: You really should show the code where you execute the query. Maybe it's just a matter of doing a ToList() somewhere to prevent re-execution, maybe the query should be revised. Who knows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct - you want the numbers og rows effected by a non-query statement?
Update, Insert, Delete (Read queries do not effect rows)

calling the `context.SaveChanges()` returns the numbers of rows affected.
`context` is an instance of your EntityModel

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the result in multiple manners:

1. Store the result count into variable and recalculate only after certain amount of time
2. Store the result count into cache (see Enterprise Library)
3. Store the result count into table and recalculate the count with a trigger on the table.

Comment: I am using ASP.Net MVC with linq which solution will be good any idea ?